# driver.quit() in Selenium : ConnectionRefusedError if used on more than one driver object

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, urllib

I have a script that can generate and run multiple chromedriver objects using selenium. The driver objects are stored in a dictionary as values and can be accessed through a string of numeric values assigned to them as keys. I have tried to create a function to quit specific drivers (as opposed to all of the running drivers) like this:

```
def quit_driver(driver_numeric_name):
    targeted_driver = drivers['driver ' + driver_numeric_name]
    targeted_driver.quit()
```

This quits one driver successfully and then I get the following error if I try to quit another one using the same function:

```
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fc8003bdd60>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

Answer (score 0):

`driver.quit()` closes all the browser instances, and thus the error '`failed to establish new connection`' as all the instances of driver are closed. You may have to try with `driver.close()` which closes the active browser.